# Is this SQL valid?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am still new to implementing joins in my db_design and i am not sure if, at all this SQL is valid.

```
"SELECT * FROM notes JOIN small_note ON notes_id = '$id' AND authname = '$author' AND bookname = '$book' AND user = '$username'"
```

A bit easier to read like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM notes
    JOIN small_note ON notes_id = '$id'
    AND authname = '$author'
    AND bookname = '$book'
    AND user = '$username'";
```

Comment: Can you show your DB structure of this two tables?

Answer (score 7):

No it isn't.

You need to specify the join columns for both tables, and you need to make sure you use a correct `WHERE` clause (which is missing from your query).

This may be more suitable:

```
SELECT * FROM notes n
JOIN small_note  sn
  ON n.notes_id = sn.notes_id
WHERE notes_id = '$id' 
  AND authname = '$author' 
  AND bookname = '$book' 
  AND user = '$username'
```

Comment: Also you shouldn't use select * especially when you have a join as it wastes resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace your first `AND` with `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

No, your $id should be the columnname that holds the reference to the other table. That's not a variable, that's a columnname